# Хранение данных в OBJECTIVE-C

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

Всегда хранил в NSUserDefaults пользовательские настройки нестрогой секретности.

Недавно случайно (а все в жизни неслучайно)))) пролистал статью о том - что данные к которым пользователь ни за что не должен получить доступ (например игровой счет в игре - количество игровых баллов) не стоит хранить в NSUserDefaults. Потому что к нему можно легко получить доступ и перебить данные

Статью пролистал поверхностно - а сейчас столкнулся с вопросом защиты переменных в приложении от возможного доступа пользователя. Так где же хранить? создавать синглтон? продолжать пользоваться NSUserDefaults? Или еще что-то?

Comment: А вот не пофиг? Ведь реальные данные всеравно хранятся на сервере?

Comment: так вот я и пытаюсь понять - пофиг или нет?

Comment: Ну то есть замарачиваться не надо и NSUserDefaults подходящее место?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К `NSUserDefaults` пользователь скорее всего не получит доступ, если только Вы не выводите значения явно в Настройки через [preferences](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html) или если к пользователю в руки не попал .ipa-пакет Вашего приложения и у него есть хорошее желание его разобрать. В таком случае его можно разархивировать и попробовать менять данные через .plist'ы которые располагаются внутри пакета в нескомпилированном виде. Начиная с iOS7 после компиляции в бинарник помимо прочего точно собираются изображения, возможно и .plist'ы(это еще нужно будет проверить). Если так то никто никогда не доберется до Ваших настроек.

Comment: Но на самом деле, с программой http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/ можно хачить любую установленную программу даже без джейла.

Comment: спасибо! меньше головной боли )

Comment: @Bimawa, "если к пользователю в руки не попал .ipa-пакет Вашего приложения и у него есть хорошее желание его разобрать"

Comment: @AlexThumb, в данном случае  эту фразу можно перефразировать: "Если пользователь не установил Ваше приложение, он его не сможет сломать"?

Comment: @AlexThumb, для меня фраза "Если так то никто никогда не доберется до Ваших настроек." звучит очень скептически. Это раньше родственники спрашивали: "Как скачать вот эту картинку вот с этой странички которая у меня открылась на экране?" На что я отвечал: "Она уже закачалась." И запомните защита системы усложняет доступ к защищенным данным, но ни когда не сможет гарантировать полную безопасность. И в данном случае я не вижу смысла защищать свою фрондЭнд систему, достаточно просто защитить данные на сервере. И пусть клиенты хачат Вашу игру, реальные данные не будут повреждены/видоизменены.